How to set an exact position for a button in a window?
I'm comfortable with Go and I'm trying to start using Gio (or Gioui), so I'm beginner in Gio.
I have a code to draw a text and a button on a window (code and screenshot). I have 2 questions:

How to split the window to 2 positions
And position the button in the top right side
As shown in the screenshot below.

My code is

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "gioui.org/app"
    "gioui.org/layout"
    "gioui.org/op"
    "gioui.org/text"
    "gioui.org/unit"
    "gioui.org/widget"
    "gioui.org/widget/material"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        w := new(app.Window)
        w.Option(app.Title("Hello World"))
        w.Option(app.MaxSize(unit.Dp(400), unit.Dp(600)))
        if err := draw(w); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
    app.Main()
}

func draw(w *app.Window) error {
    var ops op.Ops
    var lblButton widget.Clickable
    var btnClickArea widget.Clickable

    th := material.NewTheme()
    btn := layout.Rigid(
        func(gtx layout.Context) layout.Dimensions {
            btn := material.Button(th, &btnClickArea, "Button1")
            return btn.Layout(gtx)
        },
    )
    columns := layout.Flex{Axis: layout.Horizontal, Spacing: layout.SpaceAround}
    for {
        switch e := w.Event().(type) {
        case app.FrameEvent:
            gtx := app.NewContext(&ops, e)

            if lblButton.Clicked(gtx) {
                fmt.Println("the label was clicked")
            }
            if btnClickArea.Clicked(gtx) {
                fmt.Println("button1 was clicked")
            }

            layout.Flex{
                Axis:    layout.Vertical,
                Spacing: layout.SpaceStart,
            }.Layout(gtx,
                layout.Rigid(
                    layout.Spacer{Height: unit.Dp(250)}.Layout,
                ),
                layout.Rigid(
                    func(gtx layout.Context) layout.Dimensions {
                        lbl := material.Label(th, unit.Sp(50), "hello world")
                        lbl.Alignment = text.Middle
                        lblButton.Layout(gtx, lbl.Layout)
                        return lbl.Layout(gtx)
                    },
                ),
                layout.Rigid(
                    func(gtx layout.Context) layout.Dimensions {
                        return columns.Layout(gtx, btn)
                    },
                ),
            )
            e.Frame(gtx.Ops)
        case app.DestroyEvent:
            return e.Err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

The code will produce the following window

How can I have the following window (my 2 above questions)

